# getting some errors ValueError: could not convert string to float: 1/1/2020

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, computer-science, k-means

To make K-Means clustering with COVID CSV

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('Monthly_COVID.csv')

print(df.head())

features = df[['Date', 'COVID-19 Death']]

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=42)  
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(features)

print(df.head())

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(df['Date'], df['COVID-19 Death'], c=df['Cluster'], cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('COVID-19 Death')
plt.title('K-means Clustering of Monthly COVID Data')
plt.show()
```

and with this csv file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5GnF.png)

for below code:

```
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(features)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-224b433dd8ef> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 
     11 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=42)
---> 12 df['Cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(features)
     13 
     14 print(df.head())
```

I got this:

changed `csv` files' stuff, didn't work.

Added some codes for making it to `dd/mm/yyyy`, didn't work.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try Converting the date column into a pandas date format then to a numeric format,
K-means Clustering only supports numeric values for features

use this to convert it

```
# Convert 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

# Convert 'Date' column to numerical timestamp
df['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Date'])
```